# How do you block console, root or other users, access to a docker container?

Tags: docker

I tried installing puppet and changing the root user's shell to '/sbin/nologin' but I can still get right into the console?

It is a centOS 7 container.

Is Docker using a socket for the connection? Could I use selinux to block the socket? If I do I fear that I will also disable docker from being able to communicate with the container at all? I have been reading through Docker Security articles but have not found a good solution.

My end goal is for the container to be an ephemeral 'black box' when it comes up. My particular user case is a local web app, so no console access will be required.

Comment: What’s your actual goal?  Remember that anyone who can run any Docker command can trivially get root access on the host, and correspondingly you can’t treat an image’s contents as “secure” in any sort of way.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am trying to best-effort harden the container. It will run locally on a user's machine, but I don't want the user to be able to access the container's underlying OS (a shell). So only thing that will need to be open on the container is either port 80 or 443.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to remove all terminal commands (bash, sh, and so on) from the container:

`docker exec [container-id] -it /bin/rm -R /bin/*`

At that point you will not be able to use `docker exec [container-id] -it bash` to get a console to the container.

If you want to be more gentle about it you can only remove the shells you have (and leave all the other commands available (like the rm command):

```
docker exec [container-id] -it /bin/rm -R /bin/bash
docker exec [container-id] -it /bin/rm -R /bin/sh
```

... and so on

Comment: That won't help at all. somebody could do a `docker cp` and put a shell back into the container.

Comment: This works! But I will have to see if it works too well. I will most likely need to run some python in the container using os commands like tar etc. and this command may have killed python's ability to interact with the system.

Comment: @JoshuaKnox Thats what I thought, and that is why I would go for the gentler approach to just delete the shells and not all bin commands. That way python and other interpreters will still be able to use commands like tar.